# Prove or disprove that $C^1(\mathbb R)$ is dense in $C^0(\mathbb R)$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, functions, proof-writing

I have pending this question for long time (it was homework :). I don't remember wich norm was stated, so we can consider added the question "Wich norm is true for?". I've searched for similar solutions, but they don't seem to get the points I've considered. If duplicate, have in mind I've searched as much as I could.

I think it is true. Informally, we can consider for any function the points where it has no derivative, a smooth function "rounding" the corner and near the same corner. But I am unsure about those, some times named "pathological functions", as can be that continuous but derivable nowhere. I am not sure how express the idea in a satisfactory symbolism.

Comment: If you just quote the Weierstrass Approximation Theorem it becomes trivial, I assume you want a self-contained proof though.

Comment: @Shanye2020 $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact...

Comment: ah yes you're right, I need to be more careful

Comment: @Rafa Budría: Surely, $C^1(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $C^0(\mathbb{R})$ in the sup norm since polynomials are enough to approximate continuous functions. What other norms do you suggest we should investigate.

Comment: The "sup norm" is not a norm on  $C^0(\mathbb R).$ However we can still talk about any  $f \in C^0$ being the uniform limit of $C^1 $  functions.

Comment: @Parish, I reckon the problem is not very precisely stated. "For some norm is true" will be enough.

Comment: @hanye2020, any hint is welcome.

Comment: I doubt that there is any norm on $C^0$ that is useful in any way.

Comment: @zhw, so we must conclude the question is meaningless, isn't it? Well, I can reformulate for a closed interval, where it seems to work the proof. Cannot I?

Comment: For a norm, probably meaningless. But the theorem I stated is not. If you restate it for a closed bounded interval, there's nothing to do, it's just Weierstrass.

Comment: I've learned a lot, the second condition is one I probably miss. Nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem with the question, in that the metric on $C^0(\mathbb R)$ is not specifed. The $\sup$-norm comes to mind, but since there are plenty of unbounded functions in $C^0(\mathbb R),$ that won't work.

Nevertheless we can prove the following theorem:

Theorem: If $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$ and $\epsilon>0,$ then then there exists $g \in C^1(\mathbb R)$ such that $|g-f| < \epsilon$ on $\mathbb R.$

Lemma: If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $\epsilon>0,$ then there exists a polynomial $p$ such that i) $p(a) = f(a), p(b)= f(b);$ ii) $p'(a) = 0 = p'(b);$ iii) $|p-f| <\epsilon$ on $[a,b].$

I'll leave the proof of the lemma to you. It follows from the Weierstrass approximation theorem and a bit of tweaking.

Proof of Thm: Let $\epsilon>0.$ Let $n \in \mathbb Z.$ By the lemma, there are polynomials $p_n$ such that on $[n,n+1],$ $p(n) = f(n), p(n+1)= f(n+1);$ ii) $p'(n) = 0 = p'(n+1);$ iii) $|p-f| <\epsilon$ on $[n,n+1].$ Simply define $g = p_n$ on each $[n,n+1].$ Because the $p_n$'s, match up nicely at the end points, they paste together to ensure that $g\in C^1(\mathbb R).$ Clearly we have $|g-f|<\epsilon$ on $\mathbb R,$ so we're done.

Comment: Thank you. I doubt anyone in my class had been able to prove the sentence. Now, I see the steps and, more important, the idea behind the polynomial approximation and, it's true, we learned about the topic, but I doubt about it.